# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of Deformation Tensor

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was reading about eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Consider an eigenvalue $ \lambda $ of a geometric multiplicity of 2.

$$Ax=\lambda x$$

If the geometric multiplicity of $ \lambda $ is 2, therefore, we can write the eigenvector $ x $ as a sum of two independent vectors say 
$$ x=a+b $$

If I am thinking in the correct direction these vectors should also give the same eigenvalue of $\lambda$ for $A$. Therefore putting the value of $ x $ in the first equation we get

$$ A(a+b)= \lambda(a+b) $$
$$ Aa+Ab= \lambda a  +\lambda b $$

I am stuck here. How can I prove that $ a $ and $ b $ have the same eigenvalue $ \lambda $?

A similar example from the book I am reading

[image]

Here also we get an eigenvector corresponding to $ F $ as a linear combination of two linearly independent vectors  $ e1 $ and  $ e2 $. I just wanna confirm whether these linear independent vectors by themself give the same eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: You need a bit more than what you say. Use the definition of geometric multiplicity in its entirety.

Comment: I am really stuck with the concept of Geometric Multiplicity. After seeing this particular video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NffFdxiQFMM I did get some intuition about GM but it's not in a way its taught in my uni. I would be grateful if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Does GM for a particular eigenvalue means that those are the number of independent vectors which form the basis for all the possible eigenvectors corresponding to that eigenvalue? Even if that is the case i should be able to solve my above equation and each of the independent vectors should give same eigenvalue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take for example the diagonal matrix 
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
It has the eigenvalue $2$ of geometric multiplicity 2, and one of its eigenvectors is 
$$
v = \begin{pmatrix}
  0\\
  0\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\implies Ax = 2x.
$$
If you take any $x=a+b$  with $a,b$ independent, it isn't true that they are eigenvectors:
$$
v = a+b =
\begin{pmatrix}
  1\\
  0\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
  -1\\
  0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Notice that $a,b$ are independent, but
$$
Aa = 
\begin{pmatrix}
  1\\
  0\\
2\\
\end{pmatrix}\ne 2a
\qquad
Ab =
\begin{pmatrix}
  -1\\
  0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}\ne 2b.
$$

The definition of Geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ is the dimension of the space of $\lambda$ eigenvectors. If $\lambda$ has multiplicity $k$, then there exist $k$ fixed independent eigenvectors $v_1,\dots,v_k$ such that any $\lambda$-eigenvector is a linear combination of $v_1,\dots,v_k$.

Comment: If I am right, this matrix stretches all the vectors in y and z-direction. And you have mentioned one the vectors in the Z direction(v) which is an eigenvector. Is any vector which is a linear combination of these two eigenvectors also an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue?

Comment: any vector that is a combination of $(0 0 1)$ and $(0 1 0)$ is an eigenvector

Comment: Thank you, professor.